# is very compact P^2-irreducible 3-manifold homotopy equivalent to a sphere or cell-quotient?

Tags: 3-manifolds

is very compact $P^2$-irreducible 3-manifold homotopy equivalent to a sphere or cell-quotient?

Comment: What do you mean by "cell-quotient"? If you mean a quotient of the three-cell via maps that identify points of its boundary, then every 3-manifold is homeomorphic to such an object.

Answer (score 1):

Such a thing is either Haken, or geometric (by Geometrization).  Waldhausen showed that universal covers of Haken manifolds are cells, and you get a sphere or cell universal covering in the geometric case for free.